# Is google cloud-data-store support reactive database programming

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, reactive-programming

Is it possible to use google-cloud-datastore as reactive database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use Cloud Datastore as a reactive database, you just have to use the Async Datastore API and you can find how to set it up [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/async).

It is important to point out though, that this is no longer the recommended solution, you should try to use Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode due to these improvements:

- Eventual consistency, all Datastore queries become strongly consistent.
- Queries in transactions are no longer required to be ancestor queries.
- Transactions are no longer limited to 25 entity groups.
- Writes to an entity group are no longer limited to 1 per second.

and it also suits the needs that you have for your reactive app. You can also check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/upgrade-to-firestore) on how you can migrate your current Datastore to Firestore in Datastore mode.